# Laravel mail with g suites and XOAUTH2

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, gmail

I have a g suites account and applications associated with my e-mails. I was looking at the Laravel mail functions but I do not see any option to log in to gmail smtp with xoauth auth type.

I was using PHPMailer with codeigniter and I had to use clientId, clientSecret and refreshToken to send emails via smtp.gmail.com

Is there any chance I can authenticate using xoauth with native laravel swiftmailer?

Comment: i think the question is bit complex just to get an idea you want to send mail with making authencation i didnt understand that

Comment: Hi, I have g suites account at google. Which allows me to use gmail for my domain. And I want to send email via that gmail account but I can do it only by phpmailer with oauth access ( https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2 )

Comment: have you configure .env file ? according to your gmail.

And how do u want to do it like you said `but I can do it only by phpmailer with oauth access `

Comment: i need to know so i can help you

Comment: Laravel does not have any option to configure oauth access.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/authentication-with-g-suite-google-apps?page=0

This discussion may help you

Answer (score 1):

Since Laravel doesn't have available configuration to set AuthMode then we need to tweak it a little bit.

1. Register a new Mail service provider in `config/app.php`:

   ```
   // ...
   'providers' => [
       // ...

       // Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
       App\MyMailer\MyMailServiceProvider::class,

       // ...
   ```
2. `app/MyMailer/MyMailServiceProvider.php` should create your own `TransportManager` class:

```

```
namespace App\MyMailer;

class MyMailServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider
{
    public function registerSwiftTransport()
    {
        $this->app['swift.transport'] = $this->app->share(function ($app) {

            return new MyTransportManager($app);
        });
    }
}
```

```

3. In the `app/MyMailer/MyTransportManager.php` we can provide additional configuration to the `SwiftMailer`:

```

```
<?php

namespace App\MyMailer;


class MyTransportManager extends \Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager
{
    /**
     * Create an instance of the SMTP Swift Transport driver.
     *
     * @return \Swift_SmtpTransport
     */
    protected function createSmtpDriver()
    {
        $transport = parent::createSmtpDriver();
        $config = $this->app->make('config')->get('mail');


        if (isset($config['authmode'])) {
            $transport->setAuthMode($config['authmode']);
        }

        return $transport;
    }
}
```

```

4. Last thing to do is to provide mail configuration with `authmode` set to `XOAUTH2` and `password` to your access token:

```

```
<?php

return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail"
|
*/

'driver' => 'smtp',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Postmark mail service, which will provide reliable delivery.
|
*/

'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to delivery e-mails to
| users of your application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Postmark e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => 587,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => array('address' => 'user@gmail.com', 'name' => 'user'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => 'tls',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => 'user@gmail.com',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Password
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
| messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
| connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
|
*/

'password' => 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail "Pretend"
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
| web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
| you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
|
*/

'pretend' => false,

'authmode' => 'XOAUTH2',

);
```

```

Comment: I am getting this error:  Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share()

Comment: As of laravel 5.4 share has been removed. You will have to use the singleton instead.

See: https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/1a1969b6e6f793c3b2a479362641487ee9cbf736

Comment: I made it work but now getting this :Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials t66-v6sm2479077lje.95 - gsmtp

Comment: btw I have refresh token not access token

Comment: and even if I get access token it may expire how do I cahnge it then inconfig? Can you help me out a bit more ? Thanks

Comment: You may also try to set `authmode => 'login'` and username and password the same as you enter while logging in to gmail.

Comment: Yes I tried refresh and access token both gives the same error. Login wont work

Answer (score 0):

Best way to handle this is with App Passwords. You set the app password up in Google account security settings, then use that password in the .env for mail_password. It may ask you to setup two-factor, that's okay as the app password will bypass that