# How to solve the Sendgrid STMP Error 250 response in Laravel

Tags: laravel, sendgrid

I am using Sendgrid for the mail service.

My Account is two factor authentication is enabled.

My .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=S4gYKuoPRBaOAy7qT__J8w
MAIL_PASSWORD=SG.APIKEYPASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Xyz Name"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xyz@xyz.com
```

If I execute the mail then I am getting below error.

**Swift_TransportException : Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "S4gYKuoPRBaOAy7qT__J8w" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response. Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response.**

And If I disable the two-factor authentication then it works with the UserName and Password of the account but sendgrid will suspend my account if I do it like this.

Can anyone faced this issue. if yes then please let me know how you solved the problem.

Comment: I think the whole point of 2fa is to have a second factor to authenticate that you are who you say you are. In a nutshell you are asking for a way to bypass 2fa. That will never happen. Maybe the email host provides a way to login using oauth or something else to get back a token and use that to authenticate yourself? ([and they do](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/authentication/#api-key-recommended)) (new problem: not sure if Laravel provides a token based email send service by default, [guess not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51584855/13211030))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using the literal value 'apikey' as the MAIL_USERNAME, and the key from an API Key that you create in Settings >> API Keys as the MAIL_PASSWORD.

They are now enforcing 2FA, and auth with keys instead of a user/password when using 2FA, starting Nov 18, 2020. I just changed over and this worked for me.

For example,

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD=SG.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. tried many solution but i didn't know MAIL_USERNAME=apikey with the literal value 'apikey' :)

Comment: Also please clear your cache with command
"php artisan cache:clear"

Answer (score 2):

We should highlight this one

```
MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
```

The string `"apikey" is literally the` MAIL_USERNAME` for all